# assembly in solidity: wrong result for and operator

Tags: solidity, assembly

Could somebody explain why the value of c variable is not 0x0c in code below:

```
function test() {
    byte b = 0x2c;
    byte c;
    assembly {
        c := and(b, 0xf)
    }
    Check(c);
}
```

The Check event shows 0x00 instead.

But code below works correctly:

```
function test() {
    byte b = 0x2c;
    byte mask = 0x0f;
    byte c;
    assembly {
        c := and(b, mask)
    }
    Check(c);
}
```

The value of c is 0x0c.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is about the way that Solidity `byte` types are represented for use in the EVM: `byte` types are all left-justified within a 32-byte word, i.e. a single `byte` type is left-shited by 31 * 8 = 248 bits before being put on the stack.

In your first example, variable `b` is a single-width `byte` type so it is put on the stack as `0x2c00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`.  However, `0xf` has no particular type, so it is put on the stack as `0x0f`, which is the same as `0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f`.  The logical `and` of these is clearly zero.

In your second example, both of the operands to `and` are explicitly `byte` types, therefore Solidity computes: `0x2c00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 & 0x0f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`, and then it reports the single byte result `c` in the Check event (the left-most byte of the result, since that's how `byte`s are stored in Solidity).

The [Remix IDE debugger](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/) is very helpful for stepping through code like this to see what's going on under the hood.  If you are going to use some assembly code I highly recommend it - as you can see there are some surprises.

Comment: You are absolutely right! More than, I suggest do not use byte in that case at all - using uint takes less gas for the same procedures.